# If I want to use the CSS from an open source project, but I don't want the JS, or vice versa, is there any mechanism in Bower to automate this?

Tags: javascript, css, npm, gulp, bower

I fear I already know the answer, but, say for example I want the CSS from Twitter Bootstrap but not the Javascript.

I have a gulp task to take everything from *bower.json*, uglify the JS and minify the CSS, and copy it to my output directory. It's all automated.

The thing is, I'm using AngularJS, meaning I don't need the Javascript from Bootstrap, nor do I need jquery, but the automated process adds these to the output anyway.

Is there any mechanism in Bower to only add certain parts of a particular library?

The alternative seems to be to maintain a whitelist of libraries for which I don't want the whole thing.

Thanks

Comment: quick and dirty .... delete all the js files

Comment: Are you using `wiredep` for the automation of adding the files to your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `Gulpfile.js`  look for the task that copies the js
it could be something like

```
gulp.src('bower_components/**/*.js')
```

Change it to be

```
gulp.src(['bower_components/**/*.js' , '!bower_components/your/path/to/unwanted/js/file.js'])
```

the `!` will exclude paths that you don't want